# fetch details from csv file on basis of name search c#

Tags: c#, winforms, csv

Step 1: I have created a C# application called : Student details

Step 2: Added four TextBoxes and named them as :

Image below to refer:

[image]

```
Studentname.Text
StudentSurname.Text
StudentCity.Text
StudentState.Text
```

**DATA INSIDE CSV FILE**

```
vikas,gadhi,mumbai,maharashtra

prem,yogi,kolkata,maha

roja,goal,orissa,oya

ram,kala,goa,barka
```

Issue is How do I fetch all the data(surname,city,state) of user prem into above textboxes studentsurname,studentcity,studentstate from csv file when I search the name in textbox 1 => studentname.Text as prem

Below is the Code where I am stuck at return null and code inside Load_Script_Click

```cs
void Connection_fetch_details(String searchName)
{
    var strLines = File.ReadLines(filePath);
    foreach (var line in strLines)
    {
        if (line.Split(',')[0].Equals(searchName))
        {
            Connection_fetch_details cd = new Connection_fetch_details()
            {
                username = line.Split(',')[1]
            };
        }
    }
    return;
}

private void Load_Script_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // load script is button 

    String con_env = textenv.Text.ToString();
    //Address Address = GetAddress("vikas");
    //textsurname.text = Address.Surname

    Connection_fetch_details cd = Connection_fetch_details(con_env);
    textusername.Text = cd.username;
}

==============================================================
Class file name : Address.class
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace DDL_SCRIPT_GENERATOR
{
    public class Connection_fetch_details
    {
        public string username { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I vote for close, because this code won't work and has multiple problems. `Connection_fetch_details cd = Connection_fetch_details(con_env);` Calls a method which has `void` as return type and tries to set it to an Instance of a class?!

Comment: @kara why is that a reason to close it? The whole point of this site is for people to post code which doesn't work, and then we help them to fix it and explain what they did wrong.

Comment: @ADyson Your answer has nothing to do with the title of the question, but possibly solves the problem. This indicates that the question is bad and won't help anybody else. This is why i vote for close and comment that it should be split and modified in order to be answered.

Comment: @kara no, that's a reason to edit the question and improve it, or at least ask the OP for clarification and give them chance to rectify the situation before rushing to close it. The question is not irretrievable. I see that you did some editing of the formatting already, but if you think the title and wording could be improved, you can do that. I agree that the title is rather too broad and actually could be more specific to their real problem - although I suspect the reason for that is that OP has not looked into or understood the problem much and therefore does not know what to focus on.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that your method is `void`, which means it doesn't return any value. So even though you may be finding a match, and creating a Connection_fetch_details object, you aren't returning that result back to the calling method.

This will fix that problem:

```
Connection_fetch_details Connection_fetch_details(String searchName)
{
    var strLines = File.ReadLines(filePath);
    foreach (var line in strLines)
    {
        if (line.Split(',')[0].Equals(searchName))
        {
            Connection_fetch_details cd = new Connection_fetch_details()
            {
                username = line.Split(',')[1]
            };
            return cd; //return the object containing the matched username
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now it will return a `Connection_fetch_details` object if there is a match, or `null` if there is no match.

---

Next, you asked about returning all the fields, not just one. For that you would need to

a) add more properties to your object

b) add more code to populate those properties from the CSV

c) add code to populate the textboxes with the results from the object.

I'm also going to rename "username" to something more relevant, since none of the field names you described in the question match that. I'm also going to rename your class to "Student", and rename your search method, for the same reason.

Here's an example:

```
Student searchStudent(String searchName)
{
    var strLines = File.ReadLines(filePath);
    foreach (var line in strLines)
    {
        var split = line.Split(',');
        if (split[0].Equals(searchName))
        {
            Student s = new Student()
            {
                firstname = searchName,
                surname = split[1],
                city = split[2],
                state = split[3]
            };
            return s; //return the object containing the matched name
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private void Load_Script_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // load script is button 

    String con_env = textenv.Text.ToString();
    //Address Address = GetAddress("vikas");
    //textsurname.text = Address.Surname

    Student st = searchStudent(con_env);
    textsurname.Text = st.surname;
    txtcity.Text = st.city;
    txtstate.Text = st.state;
}

namespace DDL_SCRIPT_GENERATOR
{
    public class Student
    {
        public string firstname { get; set; }
        public string surname { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: ADyson Thank's I  will try your above code and let you know if any issue I face

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish your goal you have to further separate your problem in more granular steps and also distinguish between what you show in your UI and what informations you hold in the background in which format.

1. Create a class with the desired properties

   ```
   public class Student { public string Name { get; set; } ... }
   ```
2. Learn how to read a csv file into such an object by using an existing library like [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) or [CsvReader](https://github.com/phatcher/CsvReader).
3. When you have something like `List<Student>` from this part. Learn how you can visualize such a thing by using some Binding (also depends on the visualization you use Winforms, WPF, etc.).
4. Depending on the visualization component it already supports filtering or you need to filter by yourself by using e.g. LINQ to get the matching elements `students.Where(student => student.Name.StartsWith(search))`.

So far a lot of smaller problems which is simply to much to answer in a single one. Please try to break down your problems into smaller ones and search for their solutions. If you get stuck, ask a new question. That's all I can do for you now.